# Flow map in a 2-dimensional torus

Tags: general-topology, ordinary-differential-equations

In my notes I have this exercise:
Let Ω be the 2-dimensional torus and $ϕ_1$ and $ϕ_2$ the angular coordinates on it (longitude
and latitude). For given constants $α_1, α_2 ∈ R$, consider the ODE:
$$\frac{dϕ_1}{dt}= α_1 , \frac{dϕ_2}{dt}=α_2$$. Give an explicit formula for the flow map: $T^t
(ϕ_1, ϕ_2) = ?$. The solution is $T^t(ϕ_1, ϕ_2)=(\alpha_1t,\alpha_2t) \pmod {2\pi}$. Could someone explain to me why? I don´t understand it.

Comment: It looks like a simple integration.

Comment: @MehmetKırdar but why mod2pi?

Comment: Because it's a torus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is there to understand?
You solve the differential equation.

$\ \begin{align} &&&&&&&&&& \frac{dϕ_1}{dt} & = α_1 \\ &&&&&&&&&& \int \frac{dϕ_1}{dt}dt &= \int α_1 dt \\ &&&&&&&&&& ϕ_1 &= α_1t  \end{align} $

And so you get your $ T^t(ϕ_1,ϕ_2) = (α_1t, α_2t)\pmod {2\pi} $. $ \mod 2\pi$ tells us that the components of $\ T^t $ result  repeat for every $ ϕ_1 $,$ ϕ_2 $ = $ 2\pi $.